# Replacing a link with an image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm not sure how to put an image in place of the link that's being echoed below. Currently this shows a link but I want to make it a clickable image instead of the link. Thank you in advance : )

```
<div class="back-button">
    <?php
        $this_page = get_post($id);
        $parent_id = $this_page->post_parent;
        if ($parent_id) {
            $parent = get_page($parent_id);
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($parent->ID).'" title="">'.get_the_title($parent->ID).'</a>';
        }
    ?>
```

I figured it out! Here's the solution:

```
                <?php
                $this_page = get_post($id);
                $parent_id = $this_page->post_parent;
                if ($parent_id) {
                    $parent = get_page($parent_id);
                    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($parent->ID).'" title="">'.'<img src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/close-icon.png" />'.'</a>';
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include an img tag inside the a tag:

```
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($parent->ID).'" title=""><img src='myImage.png'/></a>';
```

You just need to replace myImage.png with the url of the image you want.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. I believe you have to use something like: get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/close-icon.png I'm just not sure how to incorporate that in the echo line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="back-button">
<?php
    $this_page = get_post($id);
    $parent_id = $this_page->post_parent;
    if ($parent_id) {
        $parent = get_page($parent_id); ?>  <a href="#" title=""><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/imagename.gif"></a> <?php  }  ?>
```

Try to use this one